# Sklearn Fit model multiple times

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Origin of the problem is common:

presence of a lot of train data, which was read in chunks. Point of interest is to fit  sequentially the desired model on chunked data sets, keeping states of previous fitting.

Are there any methods except `partial_fit()` to fit model using sklearn on different data? or is there any tricks to rewrite code of `fit()` function to customize it for this problem? or is it possible somekow realize with `pickle`?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `partial_fit()`?

Comment: @0x60, probably, because partial_fit works on a subset of models only.

Comment: exactly, because a range of available methods is limited

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a reason why some models expose `partial_fit()` and others don't. Every model is a different machine learning algorithm and for many of these algorithms there is just no way to add an element without recalculating the model from scratch.

So, if you have to fit the models incrementally, pick an incremental model that has `partial_fit()`. You can find a full list on [this documentation page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#incremental-learning).

Alternatively, you can build an ensemble model. Create a separate `Classifier()` or `Regression()` for every chunk of data you have. Then, when you need to predict something, you can just

```
for classifier in classifiers:
  votes[classifier.predict(X)] += 1
prediction = numpy.argmax(votes)
```

or, for regressors

```
prediction = numpy.mean([regressor.predict(X) for regressor in regressors]
```

Comment: Yes, this is the point I was wondering about. I understand that some of the ML algorithms hardly possible to be refit. So there is no other way as having large RAM for the methods without `partial_fit()`? I thought that there may be a way to save fit results and compare it somehow with results achieved after new fit.

Comment: I see. Thrown another idea into the answer.